# How to remove prepended text from option in select list

Tags: jquery, html

I currently build a select list up via a DB call and then loop through the results and build the list up like this:

```
$('#CurrentAuthority').children().remove().end();
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('#CurrentAuthority').append($('<option></option>').attr("value", data[i].CurrentAuthorityId).text(data[i].CurrentAuthority));
}
$('#CurrentAuthority').prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'>--Please Select Authority--</option>");
```

When i try and set a value to `$('#CurrentAuthority').text()` i am getting the selected option but also the `--Please Select Authority--` which was prepended.

Is it possible to remove the prepended text?

and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to query only the selected option:

```
$('#CurrentAuthority > option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use append for first text also :-

```
$('#CurrentAuthority').children().remove().end();
$('#CurrentAuthority').append("<option value='' selected='selected'>--Please Select Authority--</option>");
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $('#CurrentAuthority').append($('<option></option>').attr("value", data[i].CurrentAuthorityId).text(data[i].CurrentAuthority));
        }
```

For selected option value you need to use below:-

```
  $('#CurrentAuthority option:selected').val();
```